# (python) sorting date without using build in function

Tags: python, sorting

python sorting date without using build in function `sort()` , but the expect i want is

```
['2010-01-12', '2010-01-14', '2010-02-07', '2010-02-11', '2010-11-16',
'2010-11-22', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-26', '2010-12-02', '2010-12-13',
'2011-02-04', '2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-11-30']
```

I did read the similar problem and try to sloved it but still stock
[How to sort things, without using the sorted build-in function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855204/how-to-sort-things-without-using-the-sorted-build-in-function)
**first version code:**

```js
import datetime

def date_sorting_operation(input_list):
  
  input_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in input_list] 

  for i in range(len(input_list)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(input_list)):

        if l[i] > l[j]:
           l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]  
  return input_list

customer_date_list = ['2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']

print (date_sorting_operation(customer_date_list))
```

**second version code:**

```js
import datetime

def date_sorting_operation(input_list):
  
  input_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in input_list] 

  for i in range(len(input_list) - 1):
     for j in range(0, len(input_list) - i - 1):
         if input_list[j].repeats > input_list[j + 1].repeats:
             input_list[j], input_list[j + 1] = input_list[j + 1], input_list[j] 
  return input_list

customer_date_list = ['2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']

print (date_sorting_operation(customer_date_list))
```

*(pic) for code and output First version:*
[image: (pic) First version code code and output]

*(pic) for code and output Second version:*
[image: (pic) second version code code and output]

**(Third version) Try just to use "input_list", remove "new_list" to save memory** if that, how can I do so?

```js
   

import datetime
 
def date_sorting_operation(input_list):
  
  new_list = []
  dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in input_list] 
 
  while input_list:
      min = input_list[0]  
      for x in input_list: 
          if x < min:
              min = x
      new_list.append(min)
      input_list.remove(min)    
  return new_list
 
customer_date_list = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']
 
print (date_sorting_operation(customer_date_list))
```

(pic) try just to use "input_list", remove "new_list" to save memory:
[image: (pic) try just to use "input_list", remove "new_list" to save memory]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import datetime


customer_date_list = ['2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']

lst = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in customer_date_list]

outLst = []
for _ in customer_date_list:
    m = min(lst)
    lst.remove(m)
    outLst.append(m.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

print(outLst)
```

Output

```
['2010-01-12', '2010-01-14', '2010-02-07', '2010-02-11', '2010-12-02',
 '2010-12-13', '2011-02-04', '2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-11-30']
```

---

AS OP says *"that can I just use one list lst, which without outLst, to save on the same list. (In saving memory purpose)"*

```
import datetime


customer_date_list = ['2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']

lst = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in customer_date_list]


for i in range(len(customer_date_list)):
    m = max(lst[i:])
    lst.remove(m)
    lst.insert(0,m.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

print(lst)
```

output

```
['2010-01-12', '2010-01-14', '2010-02-07', '2010-02-11', '2010-12-02',
 '2010-12-13', '2011-02-04', '2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-11-30']
```

Comment: fantastic @codester_09 one more question that can I just use  one list  **lst**  , which without **outLst** , to save one the same list. (In saving memory purpose)

Answer (score 3):

Actually your list of text dates are *almost* in an ISO sortable format, except that occasionally the month may be one digit instead of two.  If we left pad the month with zero, sorting should work:

```py
customer_date_list = ['2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']
output = [re.sub(r'-(\d)-', r'-0\1-', x) for x in customer_date_list]
output.sort()
print(output)

['2010-01-12', '2010-01-14', '2010-02-07', '2010-02-11', '2010-12-02',
 '2010-12-13', '2011-02-04', '2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-11-30']
```

Comment: hi @Tim Biegeleisen That I wa trying to not use  `.sort() function` to sort the date myself but seems the date format `date.time` stop me for doing this. Therefore, how can I correct it though.

Comment: See the other answer.  You can also cast/parse each datetime string to a bona fide datetime, and then sort that.